# Get JSON array contents with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json, api

I'm stuck, (new to JavaScript) so I don't want to use Jquery. 
However I do need to do the following in JavaScript. It's a simple get/decode and loop array.

```
<?php 
    $url = "http://data.police.uk/api/forces"; // Make the url
    $c = file_get_contents($url); // Get JSON
    $forces = json_decode($c,true);  // Decode JSON

    foreach( $forces as $obj ) { 
    echo $obj['id'];
                 } ?>  <!-- End Loop -->
```

Thank you for your support, you guys are great!

Comment: Well unless you want to use raw XMLHttpRequest() objects (and handle fallbacks for older browsers), you'll want to use jQuery.  If you're not using jQuery anywhere else, you can always use [this website](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/) to build a version that's just their $.ajax() function.

Comment: If you're new to Javascript, you **should** use jQuery. I don't use jQuery because I'm not new to JS (I use another framework I like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API supports JSONP:

```
http://data.police.uk/api/forces?callback=your_callback
```

So you can just create a `<script>` tag:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://data.police.uk/api/forces?callback=your_callback';
script.type = 'text/javascript';

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

And register a global callback function that will run when that script loads:

```
window.your_callback = function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ...
    }
};
```

But jQuery is nicer:

```
$.getJSON('http://data.police.uk/api/forces?callback=?', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially writing a parser - but you might want to check this blog out:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1780-Using-Javascript-s-Function-Constructor-To-Deserialize-JSON-Data.htm